# What is the VB equivalent to this C# code?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have the following line in C#:

```
test.testMethod.Foreach(x => x.testMethod2.Add(test_arg));
```

What would be the equivalent in VB?

I tried to do `x => x.testMethod2.Add` but it is not allowing me to.

Comment: this is lambda syntax.. see this tutorial on how to use lambda syntax in VB http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163362.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx).
An appropriate equivalent in vb.net will be

```
Sub(x) x.testMethod2.Add(test_arg)
```

You are basically using `Function` in case you are are creating expression function and `Sub` in case you are creating expression subroutine. See [Lambda Expressions (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

It's a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb531253.aspx). The VB equivalent to that C# lambda expression would be:

```
Sub(x) x.testMethod2.Add(test_arg)
```